# Java groupby column and find average

Tags: java, java-8

I have the data which I am reading from CSV in below format.

```
accountId, recordType, amount
1, past, 40
1, past, 40
1, present, 60
2, past, 20
2, present, 10
2, present, 60
```

Whats the simplest way I can process this to group by account id and recordType and find average on amount.  I know it can be done with structures, multiple hash maps etc which make code look ugly

Expected output

```
accountId, recordType, amount
1, past, 40
1, present, 60
2, past, 20
2, present, 35
```

Here is what i tried, its incomplete, but thats the approach i was not happy about

```
//Map to store count of accountId to events
Map<String, Float> countHistory = new HashMap<String, Float>();
Map<String, Float> countPresent = new HashMap<String, Float>();

//Map to store count of accountId to sum of instance launched
Map<String, Float> amountPresent = new HashMap<String, Float>();
Map<String, Float> amountHistory = new HashMap<String, Float>();

for(LaunchEvent e : inputList) {
    if(e.getDataset().equalsIgnoreCase("history")) {
        countHistory.put(e.getAccountId(), amountHistory.getOrDefault(e.getAccountId(), 0.0f) + 1.0f);
        amountHistory.put(e.getAccountId(), amountHistory.getOrDefault(e.getAccountId(), 0.0f) + Float.valueOf(e.getAmount()));
    } else {
        amountPresent.put(e.getAccountId(), amountPresent.getOrDefault(e.getAccountId(), 0.0f) + 1.0f);
        amountPresent.put(e.getAccountId(), amountPresent.getOrDefault(e.getAccountId(), 0.0f) + Float.valueOf(e.getAmount()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The Stream API has collctors to do that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-

Comment: At least show us what you have tried.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet. I took his idea and simplified the  solution without needing extra class.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> res = events.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LaunchEvent::getAccountId,
                Collectors.groupingBy(LaunchEvent::getRecordType,
                Collectors.averagingDouble(LaunchEvent::getAmount))));
```

This will produce the output

```
Result {1={past=7.5, present=15.0}, 2={past=10.0, present=35.0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use Java as an OO language, where you can define classes and objects.

Each row is an account with three fields. So let's define a class `Account` that has these three fields.

You want to group accounts by a key, composed of two fields of the account. And if the two fields are equal, then the keys should be equal. So let's define a class `AccountGroupingKey` which represents that key and properly overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

For each key, you want the average of the amounts of the accounts having that key. So you want a `Map<AccountGroupingKey, Double>`.

How to create this map? By using the `groupingBy`collector, since you want to... group the accounts by key. And we'll use the `averagingInt` collector to transform each group of accounts into an average of integers.

So in the end, all you need is the following.

It might look verbose, but if you omit the autogenerated getters, equals and hashCode and concentrate on the logic, it's actually extremely succinct and readable.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AccountGroupingAndAveraging {

    static class Account {
        private final int id;
        private final String type;
        private final int amount;

        public Account(int id, String type, int amount) {
            this.id = id;
            this.type = type;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
    }

    static class AccountGroupingKey {
        private final int id;
        private final String type;

        public AccountGroupingKey(Account account) {
            this.id = account.getId();
            this.type = account.getType();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            AccountGroupingKey that = (AccountGroupingKey) o;
            return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(type, that.type);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id, type);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Account> accounts = Arrays.asList(
            new Account(1, "past", 40),
            new Account(1, "past", 40),
            new Account(1, "present", 60),
            new Account(2, "past", 20),
            new Account(2, "present", 10),
            new Account(2, "present", 60)
        );

        Map<AccountGroupingKey, Double> result =
            accounts.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(AccountGroupingKey::new,
                                      Collectors.averagingInt(Account::getAmount)));
        result.forEach((key, average) -> System.out.println(key.id + ", " + key.type + ", " + average));
    }
}
```